# Generate items based on previous values that are periodic in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table of reports with their dates, which are periodic, meaning that there should be a report every 6 months. I have a calendar in my application that I use to display dates for reports that have not yet been done, as a means of planning into the future. Currently, I have managed to display reports that have not yet been done for a six month interval. For example, if I had a report on 01.01.2017, the calendar will correctly show that a new report is needed on 01.07.2017 when passed a 30 day interval that contains this date. This is the query I use for this:

```
SELECT a.komitent_id,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(str_to_date(a.report_date, '%d.%m.%Y')), "%d.%m.%Y"),
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(DATE_ADD(str_to_date(a.report_date, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)), "%d.%m.%Y") 'datum_isteka'
FROM izvjestaji_aparata a
WHERE str_to_date(a.report_date, '%d.%m.%Y') < str_to_date(:start, '%d.%m.%Y')
AND DATE_ADD(str_to_date(a.report_date, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    BETWEEN str_to_date(:start, '%d.%m.%Y') AND str_to_date(:end, '%d.%m.%Y')
GROUP BY a.komitent_id;
```

Start and end params are passed from PHP and reprsent a monthly interval(from FullCalendar)

But now I want to show reports for a range of 01.01.2018 to 31.01.2018. For example, if I had a report with date between that 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc. years ago or(6, 12, etc.) months ago I should show it in this calendar.

I have been thinking of trying to do something with TIMESTAMPDIFF and MOD, 6 = 0, but I cannot use it for dynamic parameters(range).

Is there any way I can achieve this with a query, or I have to employ PHP logic to do this?

EDIT:

To rephrase, the problem is comparing dates to all dates in passed range :start to :end. I need every date from this range whose difference with a.report_date in months is divisible by 6.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is the function you want.

Comment: @serakfalcon can you show me an example?